# How can I get argument in onopen with sockJS

Tags: sockets, websocket, tornado, sockjs

I'm using SockJS client:

```
var url = "http://chatsocial.me:8888/sockjs";
var sockJS = new SockJS(url)
```

and my server:

```
def on_open(self, request , third):
        pass
```

I want to send third argument how can I send?

Comment: If you want to send data from client to server, then send it as message, not as connection event.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send data on_open, but you have to send a message after the connection is open. Please see:
http://sockjs-tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-query-string-parameters-or-cookies-to-pass-data-to-the-server

In the example they use sock.onconnect in the javascript portion, but I had to use sock.onopen in order for it to work.